# Set/get variables in loop in xslt or another solution

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

Need to convert HTML table to XML. In HTML we have table header like that

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td colspan="2">45</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
<table/>
```

In XML result must be counter throw all  elments considering rowspan attribute value.

```
<zr>
  <zc r="1" l="1">
    <zl>1</zl>
  </zc>
  <zc r="2" l="1">
    <zl>2</zl>
  </zc>
  <zc r="3" l="1">
    <zl>3</zl>
  </zc>
  <zc r="4" l="2">
    <zl>45</zl>
  </zc>
  <zc r="6" l="1">
    <zl>6</zl>
  </zc>
  <zc r="7" l="1">
    <zl>7</zl>
  </zc>
</zr>
<zr>
  <zc r="1" l="1">
    <zl>1</zl>
  </zc>
  <zc r="2" l="1">
    <zl>2</zl>
  </zc>
  <zc r="3" l="1">
    <zl>3</zl>
  </zc>
  <zc r="4" l="1">
    <zl>4</zl>
  </zc>
  <zc r="5" l="1">
    <zl>5</zl>
  </zc>
  <zc r="6" l="1">
    <zl>6</zl>
  </zc>
  <zc r="7" l="1">
    <zl>7</zl>
  </zc>
</zr>
```

In XMLT I don't know how to set/get variables in loop. Is this possible?
XMLT 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible, because XSLT is a functional language. It doesn't have mutable variables and it doesn't have loops. (xsl:for-each is not a loop, it is a mapping expression, which applies the same operation to every item in a sequence, conceptually in parallel rather than sequentially).

The way to solve your problem (as is often the case in functional languages) is with recursion: specifically, a technique I call "sibling recursion".

From the tr element, process the first td child:

```
<xsl:template match="tr">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="td[1]" mode="sib">
  <xsl:with-param name="col" select="1"/>
 </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

From the td element, process the next sibling td child:

```
<xsl:template match="td" mode="sib">
 <xsl:param name="col"/>
 <zc col="$col"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::td[1]" mode="sib">
  <xsl:with-param name="col">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@colspan">
        <xsl:value-of select="$col + @colspan"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$col + 1"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:with-param>
 </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

(It's much less verbose with XSLT 2.0!)